# Resize Tables in Excel from Access

Tags: excel, vba, loops, ms-access, resize

The following code in theory should resize my excel tables when run from Access.  I receive no errors when this is run but the tables in my excel file do not resize to all the data in the worksheets.  Any help is much appreciated!

```
Dim appExcel As Object
Dim stWorkbook As Object
Dim varName
Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set stWorkbook = appExcel.Workbooks.Open("G:\Home\RiskMgtReports\Reporting      Database\Excel\DealerProfit.xlsx")

For Each varName In Array("DLR_ALL", "DLR_ACTIVE_DESC", "DLR_ACTIVE_ALPHA", "DLR_ACTIVE_UPF", "DLR_TERM_ALPHA", "DLR_TERM_DESC")
With stWorkbook.Worksheets(varName).ListObjects("tbl" & varName)
  .Resize stWorkbook.Worksheets(varName).Range(varName)
  With .DataBodyRange
    .Interior.Pattern = xlNone
    .Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
  End With
End With
Next varName

stWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
appExcel.Quit
Set appExcel = Nothing
```

Comment: Does the code work from within Excel VBA?  Do the tables resize at all?

Comment: I did try this from excel and it doesn't work there. I've had it work in Access a few times but now it's not working again. I can't figure out why it worked a few times and now it doesn't.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that Range(varName) is a different size to Listobject("tbl" & varName)?  You could try the code in Excel again and use Range(varName).select to see exactly what size that range is.

Answer (score 0):

It is maybe not written for VBA, but there is a C# solution which does `sheet.Columns.AutoFit(); sheet.Rows.AutoFit();` Maybe something similar exists for VBA. Seems that it is close to what I found here: http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=40 In that case : `Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit`

Comment: Thanks for your post.  What I'm actually looking to do is to extend an excel table down so all the data is within the table.

Comment: I don't know how you paste it in Excel, but what I did once was, while pasting HTML code which represented a table into Excel with PasteSpecial, the Excel itself created a real table in Excel from the HTML code. In your case, if you want to extend the table down, you might do it other way around, instead of columns, maybe you fit the rows instead.